# Can we have relation like - Grails hasMany-belongsTo and instance variable

Tags: grails, orm

```
Class A
{

   static constraints =  {
      bObj(nullable:true)

   }

   B bObj
   static hasMany = [listB:B]

}

Class B
{
    static constraints =  {
       aObj(nullable:true)
    }
    A aObj
}
```

Problem that Im facing is, when I retrive instance of A(whereas bObj.aObj is null) & call save on it, automatically adds reference of A into bObj.aObj, which was null before calling save().

Any thoughts on why would it happen.

Comment: What behavior do you expect ? Could you provide clearer question ?

Comment: @araxn1d : Here actually I m trying to build a One-to-Many and has a relationship from A to B. [For 1-M instead of belongsTo, I'm directly adding nullable object of A in B]. But the kind of problem I'm facing here is with mongoDB only. Works well with MySql. so I'm assuming something is wrong with MongoORM